# EF5 CodeFirst startup performance: generate edmx model at compile time?

Tags: performance, entity-framework, edmx

My application uses EF5 with DbContext and about 100 entity classes.
Initializing the first context instance takes about 5 seconds and about 1 second for the first query.
After creating precompiled queries, the needed time reduced to 4.5 seconds and 0.1 seconds.

So, it seems that view generation especially speeds up the first query.
But the first context initialization seems to benefit only marginal from precompiled queries.

In my understanding, EF creates an EDMX model from the entity classes at runtime.
Maybe this causes the delay at startup.
I would like to move as much as possible from the startup generation to compile time.
Why should a program compute things identically on each startup?

If the generated data are dependent on for example the connection string,
I would like to store them once for each individual dependence.
Maybe there is some property containing the generated data I can serialize to a file and load it again to suppress the startup delay?

When I look into the databases migrations table, there is an encoded and compressed EDMX contained.
It seems this one will be compared to the current one to determine schema changes.
To archive this, EF has to generate an EDMX on every startup. Again and again.....
This one I like to cache for speed up.

At runtime, when the application can trust the database schema is current,
I think EF should simply use this datbase stored EDMX anyway?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for pre-compiled views (.NET representation of EDMX). Normally these views are generated at runtime but you can use [EF Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/72a60b14-1581-4b9b-89f2-846072eff19d) to have them generated at design time as a separate project file and build them together with your project.

Migration table contains EDMX but it should not affect your performance unless you are doing a migration.

Comment: I accidentally misnamed "pre-compiled views" with "procompiled queries". In fact I am using this optimization. But it gained only about 20% advantage.

Comment: Are you using .NET 4.5?

Comment: Yes, I am using .NET 4.5

Comment: I traced the first context instancing using InsightProfiler. 40% of the context constructor was used by Entity.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext. The remaining 60% of the time was eaten by CreateDatabaseIfNotExists.InitializeDatabase. I found out, when I replace this initializer with an do-nothing initializer implementing IDatabaseInitializer<Context>, the complete startup was speed up from 6 seconds to 2 seconds ! Great!

Comment: The remaining 2 seconds are used to create the model using Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build and the model compiling, resulting in an instance of DbCompiledModel. I really would like to cache this DbCompiledModel like EF does, but persistent to be used on the next startup when no change of the database connection string occoured. Any hint how to reach this?